# knitr does not build vignette

Tags: r, rstudio, vignette

I am writing a package vignette with `Rmarkdown`. I tried to follow all the tuto from Hadley, Yihui, Rstudio cheat sheet... but I still don't manage to embed the vignette correctly.

For now I have a `.Rmd` file which compiles fine by pressing Rstudio button "knit". However:

- `devtools::build_vignettes()` returns `NULL`
- building a source package and running `R CMD INSTALL` does nothing to the `/vignettes` folder
- I have checked the box `use roxygen for vignette` in Rstudio parameters
- when I compile with Rstudio, it saves the .pdf output in a wired temp directory:

> Output created:
>   /private/var/folders/53/l9bfpvgj4y7brgnjwym34kph0000gn/T/RtmpydyKqk/preview-ffc141c28b47.dir/mistral-vignette.pdf

Since my vignette is pretty long to build I would be happy to just include the .pdf output

---

The YAML input:

```
---
title: "Using mistral for reliability analysis"
author: "Clément Walter"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output: rmarkdown::pdf_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Using mistral for reliability analysis}
  %\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
---
```

In the DESCRIPTION file, I have added:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown
```